# createNativeQuery to select specific Columns given in entity POJO

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a table called `CUSTOMER` which contains 100+ COLOUMNS. But I want to select only 6 columns which I specified in my POJO:

**Entity POJO:**

```
  @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
    public class CustomerEntity {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "C_ID")
        private String customerId;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "C_KEY")
        private String customerKey;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
        private String lastName;

        @Column(name = "AGE")
        private String age;
    }
```

**NativeQuery:**

```
String query = "select * from CUSTOMER where (C_ID= '1' AND C_KEY= '12') OR (C_ID= '1' AND C_KEY= '13')) AND AGE>25";

Query q = e.createNativeQuery(query,CustomerEntity.class);
```

**[Edit : For the reason to go with Native query]**

**Reason to choose Native Query :**

1. I need to execute the below complex query in JPA.
2. In the complex query, I have subqueries, analytical method call. I assumed If I need to achieve this, then a native query will help.
3. The above native query I wrote is just to test the inner most query.

**Complex Logic:**

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT row_number() over(order by C_ID, C_KEY) RN, FEW-COLUMNS(
    SELECT * FROM BOOK
        WHERE (C_ID, C_KEY) IN (customerId1, customerKey1)
                               (customerId2, customerKey2)
                               (customerId3, customerKey3)
                               .....

                               (customerIdn, customerKeyn) AND ROWNUM <= 340
   )WHERE RN BETWEEN anyNumber and anyNumber 
)ORDER BY DESC RN;
```

**Issues:**

1. Since it is a namedQuery I am not able to pass the query as

   String query = "select cu from CustomerEntity cu where ((cu.customerId = '1' AND cu.customerKey = '12') or (cu.customerId = '1' AND cu.customerKey = '13') AND cu.age > 25)";

If I use this query I am getting `ORA -00947` Table or view doesn't exist Exception.

2. Is it possible to get only the specific columns?

Comment: The second query you wrote doesn't look ok. What is 'ct' in this query? what is 'cu' ? is that the exact query you use?

Comment: String query = "select ct from CustomerEntity ct where ((ct.customerId = '1' AND ct.customerKey = '12') or (ct.customerId = '1' AND ct.customerKey = '13') AND ct.age > 25)";  maybe like that

Comment: @Rjiuk, I meant to keep alias name(cu) for the Entity POJO. Now I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use aliases in order for this to work. Otherwise the persistence provider will not know how to perform the match:

```
select c_id as customerId, c_key as customerKey...
from CUSTOMER 
where ...
```

Aliases should be exactly the same as corresponding field names of the entity class your mapping to.

Comment: Do you mean I need to to use the select query with aliases for every column in the method createNativeQuery. (For the issue table or view does not exist)

Comment: yes, you plan to have only 6 columns in the select so its not much of hastle

Comment: Ok. But in of my another entity I need to select more than 40 columns. In that case it will be a big query If I select each column name? Any alternative way to simplfy th query

Comment: how  do expect to specify a subset of columns without doing it explicitly? Or maybe you want to select all the columns? Why use native query in that case then?

Comment: I have added the reason to go with native query in my question.

Comment: Can you advise If going via NativeQuery for the complex query will be decreasing the performance(I know that It wont be that best as If the Database is changed then I need to change the entire query)? Or any other best solution please (because my logical query contains many sub queries ans analytic method/row_number  over method)?

Comment: Native query will in general always be faster. You simply loose though all the orm benefits, including the database change rewrite. Your query though because of the complexity.. i would create a stored procedure out of it and use JPA API to call procedure. IF the db changes you wold only need to rewrtie the procedure without changing the java code / configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I need. I will try in Stored Procedure.